# A generic error occurred in GDI+ exception when trying to save image into MemoryStream

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, gdi+, memorystream

I am using C# windows form.

My code :

```
private void Openbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            SurveyDiagrampictureBox.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(openFileDialog.FileName);

            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            SurveyDiagrampictureBox.Image.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            SurveyDiagram = memoryStream.GetBuffer();
        }
}
```

It doesn't always occur, the exception throws when stepping to this line :             `SurveyDiagrampictureBox.Image.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);`

Exception message :

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in
>   System.Drawing.dll
>
> Additional information: A generic error occurred in GDI+.

Comment: Shot in the dark: Try initializing the MemoryStream with a capacity value slightly more than the expected size of the jpeg file. (Width*height is probably a decent estimate).

Comment: @JatSing this is such a common error, 40,000 pages on google. If you want us to help `provide a repro - including a image`. In the past I've got this error on a very large website and when we tracked it down the image was actually corrupt, but there is a plethora of other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

GDI+ Bitmaps are not thread-safe, so often these errors arrive from the image being accessed on multiple threads. It seems like that could be occurring here (e.g. the PictureBox rendering the image and the image being saved on your button click handler thread).

What about assigning the Bitmap to the PictureBox after completing the saving operations?

```
private void Openbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Image img = Bitmap.FromFile(openFileDialog.FileName);

            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            img.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            SurveyDiagram = memoryStream.GetBuffer();

            SurveyDiagrampictureBox.Image = img;
        }
}
```